# Concurrence property of certain straight lines generated by a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in circle $\omega$. The opposite sides $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at $M$. Point $N$ is on $\omega$ such that $MN$ is tangent to the circle. $NB$ intersects $AC$ at point $P$. Given that $MN\parallel AC$, prove that $AN$, $DB$ and $PM$ concur.

My ideas so far: Let $R$ be the intersection of the circumcircle of $\triangle$$ABP$. $R$ is the radical center but I am not sure what the three circles are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment.** First, how difficult is it to make sure that $MN \, || \, AC$? Simply pick a point $M$ outside the circle $\omega$, draw one of the two tangents to $\omega$ through $M$, and denote by $N$ the point tangency of that line with $\omega$. Then, pick an arbitrary point $A$ on $\omega$, draw the line through $A$ parallel to $MN$, and let it intersect the circle $\omega$ for the second time at $C$. Thus, $B$ is the second intersection point of $AM$ with $\omega$ and $D$ is the second intersection point of $CM$ with $\omega$. Finally, $P$ is the intersection point of $NB$ with $AC$.

**Proof.** Let $K$ be the intersection point of $MN$ and $BD$. Then $$\angle \, KDM = \angle \, BDC = \angle \, BAC = \alpha$$ as angles inscribed in $\omega$. On the other hand, since $MN \, ||\, AC$
$$\angle \, KMB = \angle \, BAC = \alpha$$ Hence $\angle \, KMB = \alpha = \angle \, KDM$. Combined with the fact that $\angle \, MKB = \angle \, DKM$, the two triangles $KBM$ and $KMB$ are similar. Consequently
$$\frac{KM}{KD} = \frac{KB}{KM}$$  which yields $$KM^2 = KB \cdot KD$$ However, due to the fact that $KN$ is a tangent of $\omega$ and $KD$ is a secant, 
$$KN^2 = KB \cdot KD$$ which means that $KM^2 =  KB \cdot KD = KN^2$. The latter identity is possible only when $KM = KN$, i.e. $K$ is the midpoint of $MN$.

Finally, observe that $APMN$ is a trapezoid. Let $Q$ be the intersection point of $AN$ and $PM$. Then, in any trapezoid, the line connecting the point $Q$ to the intersection point $B$ of the diagonals $AM$ and $PN$ of $APMN$ must necessarily pass though the midpoint $K$ of the side $MN$ (as well as through the midpoint of $AP$). Therefore, the point $K$ lies on $QB$, meaning that the line $KB$ passes through $Q$. However, by construction, point $D$ also lies on $KB$ which means that the line $DB$, being the same as line $KB$, passes through the intersection point $Q$ of $AN$ and $PM$.

Comment: Nice! My solution actually involved Pascal's theorem by using NNBCDA as a cyclic pentagon.

Comment: @mathcounter Pascal's theorem is a result of projective geometry and does not take into account parallel property. There should be more to the proof that just Pascal's theorem. If you really have a solution, you should edit your post to include them or write them as an answer.

Comment: @mathcounter and by the way, it is recommended that you vote on the answers of people who answer your questions. In addition to that, if someone provides  an answer you seed, you should accept their answer. Otherwise it is disrespectful to not show appreciation for people's efforts to answer your questions.

Comment: I am very new to this site and did not know that this was a custom. I have voted and accepted your answer now.

Comment: @Futurologist When you say "Pascal's theorem is a result of projective geometry", I agree, but I do not plainly adhere to the following formulation "and does not take into account parallel property". It does not by itself, but parallelism can be taken into account into the framework of projective geometry.